# CakePHP 3 Combine or Merge Validators

Tags: validation, model, cakephp-3.0

I have created 3 different Validators in my CakePHP 3 Model\Table each which work individually as expected.  There is a case where I'd like to combine all those rules into into one Validator and use it to validate a larger set of data.  I'm unclear as to how to go about this.  Could I get some help on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you have the following validators:

```
public function validationDefault($validator) {
    ...
    return $validator;
}

public function validationSpecial($validator) {
    ...
    return $validator;
}
```

You can create a third validator by merging the other 2:

```
public function validationFull($validator) {
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);
    return $this->validationSpecial($validator);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as expected and solved my issue.